# Why can't I upload files to SFTP home folder?

Tags: 14.04, server, ssh, ftp

I configured SFTP using the guide “[Remote Access over SFTP on Ubuntu 14.04](http://richardgreenwood.ca/2014/05/remote-access-sftp-ubuntu-14-04/)”, but I’m confused by the directory structure. Why should I create another folder inside the home directory for upload? “[How to set up FTP server on Ubuntu 14.04](http://www.krizna.com/ubuntu/setup-ftp-server-on-ubuntu-14-04-vsftpd/)” gives the same guidance. I need to upload documents directly to the home folder. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Both guides are for securing SSH access and limiting users to an SFTP-only chroot. For just SFTP access, all you need to do is:

```
sudo apt-get install ssh
```

Nothing more.

Answer (score 1):

Now Muru's *excellent* 100% correct answer in human speak: If you want access for yourself to your own machine, `sudo apt-get install ssh` is all you need!

If you want to allow *other people* into your machine, better create another (sub) directory and limit those users to that directory!  ;-)